# Permission Issues with command in rc.local

Tags: boot, bash, permissions

I am using a command to start a screen session and run a bash script for a user.

`/bin/su username -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '/home/username/test.sh; exec bash'"`

When I boot, I am seeing the screen session appear for that user, but when I open it, I see a permission denied error.

I checked permissions on the file and it is:
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 username www-data    816 Feb 18 00:59 test.sh`

Anyone have a theory why I am seeing this error? I can run the script no problem when I am logged in as username.

Answer (score 2):

`test.sh` is not executable. So you can run it by passing it as an argument to a shell, as in `bash /home/username/test.sh`, but you can't run it directly as a program like in your example command. Run `chmod +x /home/username/test.sh` to make it executable.

If `test.sh` is doing things like setting environment variables, they only survive for the duration of the process. So if you run `/home/username/test.sh; exec bash` then the final interactive shell won't have the environment variables from that process. To keep the environment variables, set them in the parent bash process: source the script, instead of running it as a separate program.

```
/bin/su username -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '. ~/test.sh; exec bash'"
```